# How does CLR optimize property references?

Tags: c#, optimization, clr, cil

I've been a programmer for a long time and have recently gotten a job writing C#. I was curious to see if Visual Studio optimized property calls to simple memory moves instead of performing a function call and return. So I wrote a program that had two versions of a 3D point class with a method to compute the magnitude: one version accesses the fields directly and one uses properties. I ran both with 100,000,000 points and they took the same amount of time. But when I use **ildasm** to look at the generated code, the version using properties seems to use a function call to access the property value. (This is a Release build, so code optimization is turned on.)

My questions:

1. Is the function call to get_X being optimized to a memory move at runtime? (It would seem so since it takes the same amount of time to execute as direct field references.)
2. Is there a way, using **ildasm** or another tool, to see which optimizations occur at runtime?

I have tried running the process without the debugger then attaching to the process but VS2017 says "No disassembly available".

The version that calls private fields directly:

```
.method public hidebysig instance float64
          Abs() cil managed
{
    // Code size       47 (0x2f)
    .maxstack  8
    //000052:             return Math.Sqrt(_x * _x + _y * _y + _z * _z);
    IL_0000:  ldarg.0
    IL_0001:  ldfld      float64 CPUTests.Point3d::_x
    IL_0006:  ldarg.0
    IL_0007:  ldfld      float64 CPUTests.Point3d::_x
    IL_000c:  mul
    IL_000d:  ldarg.0
    IL_000e:  ldfld      float64 CPUTests.Point3d::_y
    IL_0013:  ldarg.0
    IL_0014:  ldfld      float64 CPUTests.Point3d::_y
    IL_0019:  mul
    IL_001a:  add
    IL_001b:  ldarg.0
    IL_001c:  ldfld      float64 CPUTests.Point3d::_z
    IL_0021:  ldarg.0
    IL_0022:  ldfld      float64 CPUTests.Point3d::_z
    IL_0027:  mul
    IL_0028:  add
    IL_0029:  call       float64 [mscorlib]System.Math::Sqrt(float64)
    IL_002e:  ret
} // end of method Point3d::Abs
```

The version that calls properties, followed by the `get_X` method:

```
.method public hidebysig instance float64
          Abs() cil managed
{
    // Code size       47 (0x2f)
    .maxstack  8
    //000052:             return Math.Sqrt(X * X + Y * Y + Z * Z);
    IL_0000:  ldarg.0
    IL_0001:  call       instance float64 CPUTests.Point3dProperties::get_X()
    IL_0006:  ldarg.0
    IL_0007:  call       instance float64 CPUTests.Point3dProperties::get_X()
    IL_000c:  mul
    IL_000d:  ldarg.0
    IL_000e:  call       instance float64 CPUTests.Point3dProperties::get_Y()
    IL_0013:  ldarg.0
    IL_0014:  call       instance float64 CPUTests.Point3dProperties::get_Y()
    IL_0019:  mul
    IL_001a:  add
    IL_001b:  ldarg.0
    IL_001c:  call       instance float64 CPUTests.Point3dProperties::get_Z()
    IL_0021:  ldarg.0
    IL_0022:  call       instance float64 CPUTests.Point3dProperties::get_Z()
    IL_0027:  mul
    IL_0028:  add
    IL_0029:  call       float64 [mscorlib]System.Math::Sqrt(float64)
    IL_002e:  ret
} // end of method Point3dProperties::Abs

.method public hidebysig specialname instance float64
          get_X() cil managed
{
    // Code size       7 (0x7)
    .maxstack  8
    //000016:             get { return _x; }
    IL_0000:  ldarg.0
    IL_0001:  ldfld      float64 CPUTests.Point3dProperties::_x
    IL_0006:  ret
} // end of method Point3dProperties::get_X
```

Comment: Since property getter is just a method call - it's quite likely it was inlined by jitter. Inlining (and many other optimizations) happens when IL is compiled to machine (assembler) code so that is where you should look to verify this (or find the real cause).

Comment: @Evk Is it possible to see the assembler code while running the Release build under VS? Like I mention in the question, I tried this but was unsuccessful.

Comment: You can, but you need to hit a breakpoint to be able to see assembly code. In release mode with optimizations regular breakpoints might not work, so easiest way is to use `Debugger.Break()` statement. Note that it might still not optimize code while running under VS debugger (not completely sure about that, but something to keep in mind if you will get unexpected results). I'd prefer to use WinDbg.

Comment: @Evk Thanks. Setting a breakpoint in the release build got me in to the Disassembly view. Before, I was just trying to hit pause thinking that I could get a disassembly view on the current document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In his book, CLR via C#, Jeffrey Richter writes:

> For simple get and set accessor methods, the just-in-time (JIT)
>   compiler inlines the code so that there’s no run-time performance hit
>   as a result of using properties rather than fields.

CLR via C# is kind of my bible, so for me, this is more than enough proof that they are inlined.

ildasm can only show you the end result of the optimizations that happen at compile time. If you want to check the runtime optimizations, you have to actually look at the runtime code, that is, the code that is generated from the assembly and is being run. S.O.S extension for WinDbg might be a tool that can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the book. I'm definitely adding that to the library.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 4):

Using disassembly view while debugging will likely show you that property getter and setter are indeed inlined. 
You can access this using CTRL-ALT-D in visual studio.

If you want to spot the Jitter optimizations, you can disable them by using [MethodImplOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
public struct foo
    {
        private int _bar;
        public int bar
        {
            [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining | MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]
            get { return _bar; }
            [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining | MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]
            set { _bar = value; }
        }
    }
```

will show you while debugging :

[image]

while if you don't put the attribute, you can't even hit the breakpoint, because all the getter has been inlined.